# apache log file size limit

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

Recently one of my apache installations went down, and after looking around we found out that it's the apache's error_log and access_log size that had reached 2GB. Once we rename the logs and create a new empty ones, everything's ok.

My OS is Redhat 4 and filesystem is ext3. According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems), a file in ext3 can have up to 16 GB to 2 TB in size. Is it the apache implementation or is it something else that rendered the apache unable to start after 2 GB?

Thank's in advance.

-A

Comment: You could use logrotate to avoid the logs growing too big. This way you won't have to deal with the consequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of apache are you using?  A quick google shows that older versions had a bug regarding logfiles that were 2gb.

Comment: turned out it's the buggy version of apache, thank's :D